# Contact form not sending mail to admin even when php and smtp mail settings were correct

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x

Contact form is not working even though the php and smtp mail settings are customized correctly.

In php mail settings, it prompts as
           "Could not instantiate mail function".

In SMTP settings, it prompts as
           "SMTP connect() failed".

Iam using Joomla 3.4.8 version and even the JSN uniform (3.3.1) is not working. Can someone clarify me ASAP please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this kind of problems few times.

Once I've had Send From email address in Global Config which was not from native site domain, and Joomla complained "Could not instantiate mail function". It was fixed the moment I changed the Send From email to one that actually exists on the server which hosts site and domain, even though it was just email forwarder. It used PHP Mail setting.

I've noticed that issue doesn't happen on every server. On some servers I've happily used sendfrom address from my own Google Apps email domain, but on others I have to use existing email address from the site domain.